# Ways to cut and reassemble a solid object

Tags: geometry

I have been puzzling over this for a few years and still have no answer.

> How many ways can a solid object like a cube or a ball be cut into pieces such that it is possible to take apart and put back together (in the real world or in math talk where each movement is a rigid body motion - translation and/or rotation)?

Clearly, some notion of isomorphism equivalence classes (math talk again) would be necessary with categories depending on the number of separate pieces.

Comment: Why can't the answer be infinite?

Comment: @Sentinel, yeah, a good first step would probably be [cutting the thing into 5 pieces and reassembling 2 copies of the original](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox)

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that there is any *practical* categorization that would work for all possible puzzles. People have designed mechanical analogues for [Turing engines](http://rsfs.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/2/4/497). So it is probably feasible to design a finite 3D block puzzle with some k*n components (where k components are sufficient to construct a single Turing engine state), that would take a number of separate manipulations comparable to BB(n) to disassemble (where BB(n) is the [busy-beaver number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver) for the n-state Turing engine).

The busy-beaver number grows extraordinarily quickly as a function of n, so it should be possible to design such a puzzle for which there wouldn't be any practical way to determine if it was soluble.